# Error when updating date field in sql server using c#

Tags: c#, sql, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to insert a date (date only, not datetime) into sql table (the datatype is date).

I am using the `'23/07/2013'` format which I am getting from jquery datepicker.

When I execute the following sql, I am getting following error.

SQL: `UPDATE qmsAuditFindings SET FindDate='23/07/2013' WHERE AuditID=37`

Please advise.

Also its worth mentioning that the insert statement with the exact format works just fine. Just the update that does not.

[image]

Comment: Your date is not in correct format to be insert in sql

Comment: you need to convert the date from varchar to date use Convert function of sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the surface, this is simply a formatting issue - but "fixing the formatting" is the wrong way to address this; you should *parameterize*, such that formatting *simply does not apply*. Dates don't *have* a "format", as such - they are just numbers. For example, what we *should* probably execute is:

```
UPDATE qmsAuditFindings SET FindDate=@findDate WHERE AuditID=@auditId
```

To do that you get the `DateTime` value in your .NET code, and do something like:

```
DateTime findDate = ...
int auditId = ...
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText =
        "UPDATE qmsAuditFindings SET FindDate=@findDate WHERE AuditID=@auditId";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("findDate", findDate);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("auditId", auditId);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or more simply with a tool like "dapper":

```
DateTime findDate = ...
int auditId = ...
connection.Execute(
    "UPDATE qmsAuditFindings SET FindDate=@findDate WHERE AuditID=@auditId",
    new { findDate, auditId });
```

Comment: Your way works great thanks. For the sake of saving time, I have done it the unsecure way.

Comment: @ReidGarwin I read that as "for the sake of saving time, I knowingly did something that could cause data loss" - but fine: your system, your call